# Multiple ports listening in laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ember.js, server

I'm doing live chat server on my laravel development, I setup everything in Digital Ocean. Setup apache2 and phpmyadmin. However, when I tried to run the

> **"php artisan serve"**(Default port:8000)

then open up my website with IP. The server commands didn't detect anything. Fine. I try my live chat server

> **"php artisan chat:serve --port=8887"**

with different ports. But didn't work for me, it shows blank screen without errors. Suppose shows me live chat messeger interface on my website but blank. I know something deals to my apache2 server, but I have no idea how to deals with it.

By the way, I'm using emberJS chat server and follow-up this tutorial at [here](https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-real-time-chat-eaa550829538)

Comment: What type of chat server?

Comment: emberJS chat server @NoBugs

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan serve` is intended for local development, and as such, limits itself to the local network by default. Doing `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` will allow it to be accessible to the public internet.

Do note that `php artisan serve` should **never** be used to serve a production site. You should be serving the live site with Apache, not Artisan.

Comment: the serve command is using fpm to serve. if your using serve with nginx or apache as a reverse proxy there is no issue.

Comment: @astroanu `php artisan serve` does NOT use PHP-FPM to serve. The source code from the command can be found at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7f62d81acb2001faafb21a32544464ebfc92476c/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php - it's doing `php -S {$host}:{$port} {$base}/server.php`, which uses the PHP development server, which is *not* production-safe. See the `-S` flag and the big red note at http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php